# Where condition is not working with condition

Tags: laravel, relation

```php
$modules = Role::with(['rights' => function ($q) {
    return $q->with('module');
}])->where('id', $user->role_id)->get();
```

Can someone help with this condition not working with the where statement?

Comment: What exactly you want to do please describe briefly? you can not return inside `with`

Answer (score 1):

You can not return inside the relation inside the `with()` closure.

Instead, you can use [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for this.

```
$modules = Role::where('id', $user->role_id)
                 ->with('rights.module')
                 ->get();
```